# javascript includes() case insensitive

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of strings that I need to loop and check against with another passed in string.

```
var filterstrings = ['firststring','secondstring','thridstring'];
var passedinstring = localStorage.getItem("passedinstring");

for (i = 0; i < filterstrings.lines.length; i++) {
    if (passedinstring.includes(filterstrings[i])) {
        alert("string detected");
    }
}
```

How do I ensure that case sensitivity is ignored here (preferably by using regex) when filtering, if the `var passedinstring` were to have strings like `FirsTsTriNg` or `fiRSTStrING`?

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as a duplicate. The advantage of using `includes` over regex is that it covers scenarios where your string contains regex special characters.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can create a **RegExp** from `filterstrings` first

```
var filterstrings = ['firststring','secondstring','thirdstring'];
var regex = new RegExp( filterstrings.join( "|" ), "i");
```

then `test` if the `passedinstring` is there

```
var isAvailable = regex.test( passedinstring );
```

---

Here is a test implementation:

```js
// Take care to escape these strings!
// If they are user-input or may contain special regex characters (such as "$" or "."), they have to be escaped.
var filterStrings = ['one','two','three'];
var regex = new RegExp(filterStrings.join( "|" ), "i");

var sentences = [
  "one", // true
  "OnE", // true
  "a rabbit", // false
  "and then two rabbits", // true
  "standing", // false
  "prone", // true
  "AoNeAtWo", // true
];
sentences.forEach(sentence => {
  console.log(
    regex.test(sentence) ? '✅ match:' : '❌ not a match:',
    "'" + sentence + "'",
    );
});
```

Comment: Note that firststringtest will also return true here.  with ES5, `filterstrings.map((a) => { return a.toLowerCase() }).includes(passedinstring.toLowerCase())` may be a solution for this problem.

Comment: `filterstrings` must be escaped, otherwise you risk ending up with a broken regex, or one with unexpected behavior.

Comment: How much slower is this comparing to .includes() ?

Comment: This shouldn't be an acceptable answer! Whoever seeks for an answer and stumbled upon this answer - BEWARE! this will return `true` for any sub sequence can be found in the array.

```[1,2,3].includes(12) // false  
new RegExp([1,2,3].join("|"), "i").test(12) // true!!!  
    
  
["Hello","World"].includes("HelloWorld") // false  \n
new RegExp(["Hello", "World"].join("|"), "i").test("HelloWorld") // true!!!```

Comment: Mapping random strings to regex patterns is not a good idea, unless you really know that those strings won't include special characters.

Comment: @TzahiLeh yes you are right but that is the behaviour that OP is looking for

Comment: @RoboRobok if you can't be sure, how do you sanitize the input?

Comment: @shieldgenerator7 you just compare strings and if it needs to be case-insensitive, compare lower- or uppercased versions of them. Simple as that.

Comment: @shieldgenerator7 I couldn't understand from the question if this is what the OP wants. Maybe it satisfies the OP, yet I wrote my comment for anyone out there who doesn't know about this regex-behaviour, which can lead to bugs

Comment: @TzahiLeh, the answer is correct, you misunderstood. I added a JS snippet to the answer, showing that it works as intended; if you still think it doesn't, please let us know of a sentence that matches wrongly in that snippet. :)

Comment: You misunderstood two things. First, your `[1,2,3].includes(12)` is checking "is my value an _exact match_ to any filter", and not "does my value contain any of the filters [=is a _partial_ match]", which is not what is being asked. Then, your `new RegExp([1,2,3].join("|"), "i").test(12)` is actually correct and **should** be true as it is - "12" _is indeed_ a match for the filters "1" and "2". If we are searching "12" to see if it _includes any of the filter strings_ ["1", "2", "3"], then it does - the first and the second filters. The "!!!" should be in the `[1,2,3].includes(12)` instead.

Answer (score 82):

ES6 array method [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can simplify the solution to a single line. Use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to determine whether an array includes a certain value among its entries in conjunction to the [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method to convert it to lowercase.

```
var filterstrings = ['firststring','secondstring','thridstring'];
var passedinstring = localStorage.getItem("passedinstring");

// convert each string from filterstrings and passedinstring to lowercase
// to avoid case sensitive issue.
filteredStrings = filterstrings.filter((str) => str.toLowerCase().includes(passedinstring.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: this is a great answer! This is a very simple single-line solution. I'm using the `filteredStrings` line within a filter, and I just check if the length > 0 in the encapsulating filter statement

Comment: Thanks - its always appreciated when people answer old questions with the latest functionality!

Comment: Using [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) would be safer. There can be problems with plain `.toLowerCase()` - please see Jon Skeet's presentation on YouTube [Back to basics: the mess we've made of our fundamental data types](https://youtu.be/l3nPJ-yK-LU?t=1266) for more information.

Comment: I've used a variation on this:
filteredstrings = filterstrings.some(e => e.toUpperCase().includes(activeSearch.toUpperCase()))

Answer (score 67):

You can simply convert the passedinstring to lowercase.

```
var passedinstring = localStorage.getItem("passedinstring").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: well, it works in the given case but I guess we want it to work the other way around as well... (i.e the filtered strings also having capital letters)

Comment: If you want the other way to work as well, just use toLowerCase() on the inputted string as well.

Answer (score 33):

You can switch `.includes` with the [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method which returns a *boolean*. 
It will **exit as soon as a match was found**, which is great  for performance for huge arrays:

```js
.some(item => item.toLowerCase() == lookup.toLowerCase())
```

#### Demo:

```js
var arr = ['foo','bar','bar'];
var lookup = "bAr";

// case-sensetive
console.log( arr.includes(lookup) )

// case-insensetive without caring about the type
console.log( arr.some(x => x.toLowerCase() == lookup.toLowerCase()) )
```

---

Or define your own *Array* prototype method with a **unique** name:

```js
// the name ("_includes") should be unique enough not to ever be overriten 
// by future language updates or 3rd-party scripts
Array.prototype._includes = function(target){ 
  return this.some(x => x.toLowerCase() == (target||'').toLowerCase()) 
}

console.log( 
  ['foo', 'bar', 'bar']._includes("bAr") 
)
```

Comment: It could be even better performance-wise, if you do `lookup.toLowerCase()` outside of the loop.

Comment: @TomášLokša - I tend to provide the simplest solution and it is up to the copy-paster to adopt it to their needs. Many answers here can be easily improved by it might not fit everyone or make the solution less easy to understand at a quick glass, which I want to avoid at some situations as this one

Comment: Ah, got it :) Anyway, thanks for your solution, it was really useful to me.

Comment: Agree with Tomas. Loop invariants are a thing.

Comment: I agree, but again, my answers here are a simplified version and not a copy-paste solutions. I tend to provide shortest meaningful answers which users can build on top

Answer (score 14):

convert filterstring and passedinstring to lowercase and compare

```
var filterstrings = ['firststring','secondstring','thridstring'];
var passedinstring = 
localStorage.getItem("passedinstring").toLowerCase();

for (i = 0; i < filterstrings.lines.length; i++) {
   if (passedinstring.includes(filterstrings[i].toLowerCase())) {
       alert("string detected");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Fixed case sensitivity issue using `toLowerCase()`. It turns all the `strings` to lower case.

```
var product=productList.filter((x) => 
x.Name.toLowerCase().includes(("Active").toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 5):

My option is comparing UPPER with UPPER or lower with lower transforming both sides (i did it often in SQL):

```js
    var filterstrings = ['firststring','secondstring','thirDstrIng'];
    var passedinstring =  'ThIrDsTrInG3';
    
    //used for of just to make it more readable
    for (filterstring of filterstrings) {
        if (passedinstring.toUpperCase().includes(filterstring.toUpperCase())) {
            alert("string detected");
        }
    
    }
```

Prompts `string detected`

Comment: Aha. That's smart. I thought that `.includes()` could only apply to an array. I see that [it can also apply to a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Answer (score 3):

I believe this would be simpler, shorter and more understandable.

```
  const q = new RegExp(query, 'i');

  filteredUsers = users.filter((user: User) => {
    return (
      user.entity.short.match(q) ||
      user.firstname.match(q) ||
      user.lastname.match(q)
    );
  });
```

Comment: This seems to be filtering a different set of data … and assumes that `query` won't include any characters with special meaning in regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

```
var filterstrings = ['firststring','secondstring','thridstring'];
var passedinstring = localStorage.getItem("passedinstring");

filterstrings.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(passedinstring.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: Your solution is very similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63030383/3216427 just replacing `(str) => str.toLowerCase()...` by `item => item.name.toLowerCase()...`. Can you explain what this difference changes and why you think this is an improved solution?

Answer (score 1):

### A non-regex approach:

I came across this issue yesterday.

I had two `arrays`, neither of which contained consistently case-formatted values:

```
let availableDays = [

  'tuesday',
  'THURSDAY',
  'Monday'
];

let orderedWeekdays = [
  
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'FRIDAY'
]
```

I needed to find out, on a case-insensitive basis, which items from `orderedWeekdays` were present in  `availableDays`.

---

### Solution:

My **non-regex** approach was, first, to create a new `array` for checking:

```
let availableDays_CheckingArray = availableDays.map((day) => day.toLowerCase());
```

And then to loop through `orderedWeekdays`, applying a `.toLowerCase()` transformation each time, prior to comparing:

```
for (let i = 0; i < orderedWeekdays.length; i++) {

  if (availableDays_CheckingArray.includes(orderedWeekdays[i].toLowerCase())) {

    [... CODE HERE...]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
string = fruits.join(' ').toUpperCase();
// Output"BANANA ORANGE APPLE MANGO"
```