# how can i make the input value case-insenstive in an array using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, case-insensitive

I want to be able to search for a value without having to explicitly type in the first letter using uppercase. Hence it can be recognised in lowerCase also. Any help please?

```
function animal(){
        var animal = ["Panda", "Snake", "Lemur", "Tortoise", "Whale", "Cat", "Elephant", "Jaguar", "Panther", "Llama", "Horse", "Cheetah", "Leopard", "Anteater", "Tazmanian Devil"];

            if(animal.includes(document.getElementById("animalName").value)){
                console.log("That animal is available");
            }
            else{
                console.log("That animal is not available at the moment");
            }

        }
```

Comment: please add the html part to the question.

Comment: Why not have them all uppercase in the array and then compare against toUpperCase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript includes() case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145432/javascript-includes-case-insensitive)

Comment: Use a regex match!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive regex in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939715/case-insensitive-regex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply test lowercase values.
Also, I would suggest to cache the input DOM element and to define the array outside of the function, so they're not uselessly redefined every time the function is called.

```
const animalName = document.getElementById("animalName"),
       animal = ["panda", "snake", "lemur", "tortoise", "whale", "cat", "elephant", "jaguar", "panther", "llama", "horse", "cheetah", "leopard", "anteater", "tazmanian devil"]

function animal(){
        let typed = animalName.value.toLowerCase().trim()

        if(animal.includes(typed)){
          console.log("That animal is available");
        } else {
          console.log("That animal is not available at the moment");
        }
}
```

Comment: you will probably want your animal name to be in the scope of the function, otherwise it won't change as the function is called (presumably called every time a user types)

Comment: I'm only caching the DOM element, that probably won't change over time.

Answer (score 1):

set both the input and internal array to lower case using the `toLowerCase` method. Since the animals are an array we map over the array and turn each item to lower case. We then get the input value and turn it into lowercase and afterwards a simple `includes` check is done.

```js
document.querySelector("#myBtn").addEventListener("click", animal);

function animal(){
        var animal = ["Panda", "Snake", "Lemur", "Tortoise", "Whale", "Cat", "Elephant", "Jaguar", "Panther", "Llama", "Horse", "Cheetah", "Leopard", "Anteater", "Tazmanian Devil"].map(animal => animal.toLowerCase()), 
         myValue = document.getElementById("animalName").value.toLowerCase();

            if(animal.includes(myValue)){
                console.log("That animal is available");
            }
            else{
                console.log("That animal is not available at the moment");
            }

        }
```

```html
<input id="animalName" />
<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>
```

ASIDE: There are better ways to do this. For instance, since you're constructing the array every time `animal` is called I could only assume you had a reason for this and decided to map over the array instead of adjusting your code. If you *don't* have a reason for this, I would advise adjusting your code to receive that array instead of building it every time.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function animal(){
  var animal = ["Panda", "Snake", "Lemur", "Tortoise", "Whale", "Cat", "Elephant", "Jaguar", "Panther", "Llama", "Horse", "Cheetah", "Leopard", "Anteater", "Tazmanian Devil"];
  var valueToFind = document.getElementById("animalName").value;

valueToFind=valueToFind.toLowerCase();
valueToFind=valueToFind[0].toUpperCase()+valueToFind.substr(1);

  if(animal.includes(valueToFind)){
    console.log("That animal is available");
  }
  else{
    console.log("That animal is not available at the moment");
  }
}
        
var button= document.body.querySelector('button');
        
button.onclick=function(){
   animal();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="animalName">
<button>test</button>
```