# javascript filter an array of strings, matching case insensitive substring

Tags: javascript

I have an array of names filtered by a certain string. How can I match all names that include this string, but insensitive of case?

```
this.employeeDisplayList = this.employeeList.filter(e => e.employeeName.includes(this.searchStr));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript includes() case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145432/javascript-includes-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.employeeDisplayList = this.employeeList.filter(e => {
    const emp = e.employeeName.toLowerCase();
    const str = this.searchStr.toLowerCase();
    return emp.includes(str);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply `.toLowerCase()` to both the employeeName and the searchString.

```js
let employeeDisplayList = [{employeeName: "Jules 1"}, {employeeName: "jules 2"}, {employeeName: "Max"}];

let searchStr = "Jules";

console.log(employeeDisplayList.filter(e => e.employeeName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr.toLowerCase()) >= 0));
```

Another way would be to search with a case insensitive regex: `string.match(/word/i)`

Comment: Apparently I got here a minute too late XD